# How to use goto instead of for, while, or switch

Tags: c

So I'm in an introductory computer science class, I don't know any C programming language, and we were not taught any. We were however told to rewrite some expressions into C using only two control structures:

```
 goto label;
 if (expression) goto label;
```

The first one is this:

```
if (i > 5)
{
   i++;
}
if (sum > 5)
{
   sum++;
}
```

to which I don't even see why anything has to change.  The second one is this:

```
sum = 0;
for (i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
   if (V[i] > 0)
   {
      sum = sum + V[i];
   }
}
```

for which I wrote:

```
sum = 0;
i = 0;
label:
if (V[i] > 0)
    sum = sum + V[i];
if (V[i] < 0)
    sum = sum;
if( i < 100)
++i;
goto label;
```

Does the code I made make sense? About the only thing I understand is that the goto takes the code to wherever it says to go.  I know a little Java, but that's it.

I'm not just looking for someone to do my work for me, but I asked my teacher for help and he only answered my question about the typo in the assignment. I think I'm just supposed to get an idea of what the goto expression does, and how lines of C code work, but I've been looking at tons of posts about why you shouldn't use goto statements, with none of them talking about how to actually *use* one.

He also said not to use {} in our new code.

Comment: That last `goto` is not bound by any condition, so it will loop forever.

Comment: Don't try to guess what C statements do; buy [a book](http://www.amazon.ca/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628) and follow it.

Comment: goto is very bad practice!

Comment: you probably want to switch the lines `if( i < 100)` and `++i;`

Comment: Just google "C for loop" and find out what the three clauses do.

Comment: Another way to find out what it does is to run it (e.g. under a debugger and use the "step" feature to step through the lines)

Comment: The first one has to change because it uses control structures other than the two that are allowed. (Of course the `if` version is much better, but the point isn't to *improve* the code, it's to understand what it does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the first part of your first example:

```
if (i > 5)
{
    i++;
}
```

Where does the control flow go if i <= 5? Where does the control flow go if i > 5? -- you should make sure you can answer this before you read on.

A direct translation would be

```
if (i > 5)
    goto if-body;
goto end-if
if-body:
    i++;
end-if:
   ....
```

You should convince yourself that the control flow in the above is the same as the original.  You can simplify this a bit by flipping the condition:

```
if(i <= 5)
    goto end-if;
i++;
end-if:
    ....
```

Again, you should convince yourself that the control flow is still the same.

From this and what Brandin gave in his answer, you should be able to do the rest of the assignment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It makes more sense now. It helps to have it brought into terms I'm more familiar with. I'm haven't simplified it, but for the second part I made a little change:

    sum = 0;
    i = 0;
    label:
    if (V[i] > 0) 
    sum = sum + V[i];
    if (V[i] < 0) 
    sum = sum;
    if (i < 100) ++i;
    if (i < 100) goto label;

Comment: @ajPetriccione You still seem to be missing a point.  With the if statement, the form is `if (exp) goto label` -- the only thing after the `if(...) is a goto.  So the code part `if (V[i] > 0) sum = sum + V[i];` isn't right.  I believe it should be translated as `if(V[i] <= 0) goto next1; sum = sum + V[i]; next1: if (V[i] >= 0) goto next2; sum=sum; next2: .... and so on.   I do have to ask, is the course teaching C or assembly, this type of exercise is more common to help people make the transition from C to assembly

Comment: Yeah, the class is to do with microcontrollers, and we have led into assembly language recently. We also did some things with arduinos, and I bought one to mess around with. Thanks for bringing that to my attention @thurizas.  Is that a hard and fast 'rule', or is that more of a convention...?  Would it crash a C compiler to have other stuff after the if, or is it just good practice? This could go on and on, and is perhaps beyond the scope of this particular assignment. I will use that structure. Thanks.

Comment: I'm basing my comments on the restrictions you  originally gave "...rewrite some expressions into C using only two control structures: `goto label ; if (expression) goto label ;` ".  If I got the intent wrong, let me know.  In C you can have any-number of statements after the if (as long as they are enclosed in `{` ... `}`).

Comment: I will post what I ended up with at the bottom @thurizas

Answer (score 2):

A *for* loop can be thought of as having the following basic form:

```
for (init; cond; inc)
    statement-block
```

The above *for* loop is basically equivalent to the following form which uses *while*:

```
init;
while (cond) {
    statement-block
    inc;
}
```

The *while* loop, on the other hand can be thought of as having the following basic form:

```
while (cond)
    statement-block
```

And it is basically equivalent to the following form using `label:` and `if (cond) goto label;`

```
loop_beg:
if (!cond) goto loop_end;
statement-block
goto loop_beg;
loop_end:
```

If you use both of these transformations then you should be able to rewrite any piece of code in C which uses `for` or `while` to do the same thing using only `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

`goto`s are actually very easy to use and understand. You write a label that marks a piece of code that you would want to go back to (or skip forward to) the label can be before the `goto` as well as after it. It doesn't matter; the reason why it's to be avoided at all cost is that it makes the code very difficult to maintain and all tangled up (yes, like spaghetti!) if that makes any sense.

And concerning your last piece of code you should bound the `goto` with a condition. Otherwise, the code will keep bouncing back and forth between `label` and `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with, following what I could [from thurizas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225961/how-to-use-goto-instead-of-for-while-or-switch/26226388#26226388) and [Brandin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225961/how-to-use-goto-instead-of-for-while-or-switch/26226227#26226227):

```
if (i > 5)
    goto ibody;
goto ifsum;
ibody: i++;
ifsum: if(sum > 5)
           goto sumbody;
goto end;
sumbody: sum++;
end;
```

And:

```
sum = 0;
i = 0;
label1: if (V[i] > 0)
            goto sum1;
if (V[i] < 0)
    goto sum2;
sum2: sum = sum;
goto labeli;
sum1: sum = sum + V[i];
labeli: ++i;
if(i >= 100)
    goto end;
if(i < 100)
    goto label1;
end;
```